# scraping video links from lazy loaded videos

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a video from a page using a package called [icrawler](https://github.com/astur/icrawler), but that video is not rendered instantly when a page loads, so when I get the `html` code of that page, the `video` tag doesn't exist but it does if I open the page in the browser and inspect.

How do i wait for the page to load the video before crawling it ?

Answer (score 0):

The page most likely loads the video using javascript so, you would need library capable of rendering/executing HTML and javascript.

I took a quick look at icrawler and according to the doc it uses [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) which quoting from its doc "does not produce a visual rendering, apply CSS, load external resources, or execute JavaScript".

The same docs mention that you could use something like [PhahomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (seems to be abandoned) or [JSDom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom). Another alternative is to use [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/).